# Getting NaN as result of a calculation from data that was dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I'm having problems with updating results of a calculation using the change method.

The calculation is made from dynamically created data that is placed into a table row.
so the last column of each row should show the total of the price * qty (qty is derived from dynamically created select element). The way to create each row is by selecting an option from the auto-complete input box.

Every time the user select the option from the select element that is in a dt ,the total of that row should be updated. it works the first time but the second time the result column turn to NaN.

[***jSfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/49axJ/3/)

I think i might have problems with how I set up the rows with the

```
 $("tr").not(":first").each(function(){// meant to not get the header but the rest of the rows which have the data for the calculations
```

or the math part. i subtracted 0 from a string to make that into a number so I think I shouldn't get NaN. I know i messed up something that prob seems obvious to you but def not to me.

> ```
>  $("tr").not(":first").each(function(){
>      var qnty = 0;
>
>     $('select').change(function(){
>         qnty = $('select').val();
>         calcTotal();
>     })
>     function calcTotal(){
>        var price = (($(".price").text()) - 0).toFixed(2)
>         $(".total").text(qnty * price);
>     }
>  })
> ```

To sum up the problem. the calculations don't work starting from the second time the row with data is created. The result in the result column is NaN. I would obviously like the result to be the calculation of qnty * price for each row in the Total column.

Here the  [***jSfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/49axJ/3/) to illustrate my problem.

Comment: What happens if you use parseInt or parseDouble instead of subtracting 0?

Comment: i tried parseInt the same thing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will be the code:

```
$("tr").not(":first").each(function(){
     var qnty = 0;
     var $row=this;
    $('select',$row).change(function(){
        qnty = $('select',$row).val();
        calcTotal($row);
    })
    function calcTotal($row){
       var price = (($(".price",$row).text()) - 0).toFixed(2)
        $(".total",$row).text(qnty * price);
    }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this changes the total of the new row and the previous rows totals to the new rows total i would like the previous rows to stay the same. thank you.

Comment: thanks but now when i want to change the qnty the result doesn't change. I would prefer that the user should have the ability to change the qnty when ever they want and in whichever row and that Total column should update immediately upon change of qnty

Comment: yes thats what I want. before I accept your answer, can you please explain why  you are using $row to store the whole row and using that element in the $().  Why would you need the whole row in the selector. for example, to place the total of the calc in the total element you use the selector $(".total",$row) why would you need the $row for just access to the total element. excuse my ignorance please. and thank you again

Comment: Second parameter in $() defines the context in which you want to apply the selector. now as you have multiple elements with same class(.total,.price) then it will always pic the first element with matching class in the page thats why i am supplying current row in seletor which says search for element with class .table in the row i passed not in the complete html page same is the case with selector. got it?